# Issue with date Histrogram aggrgation with filter

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to get date histrogram for a timestamp field for a specific period. I am using the following query,

```
{
  "aggs" : {
    "dataRange" : {
      "filter": {"range" : {  "@timestamp" :{ "gte":"2020-02-28T17:20:10Z","lte":"2020-03-01T18:00:00Z" } } },
       "aggs" : {
        "severity_over_time" :{
            "date_histogram" : { "field" : "@timestamp", "interval" : "28m" }
        }}}
  },"size" :0
}
```

The following result I got,

```
{
  "took": 6,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 1,
    "successful": 1,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": {
      "value": 32,
      "relation": "eq"
    },
    "max_score": null,
    "hits": []
  },
  "aggregations": {
    "dataRange": {
      "doc_count": 20,
      "severity_over_time": {
        "buckets": [
          {
            "key_as_string": "2020-02-28T17:04:00.000Z",
            "key": 1582909440000,
            "doc_count": 20
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The the start of the histogram range ("key_as_string" ) goes outside of my filter criteria! My input filter is from "2020-02-28T17:20:10Z" but the **key_as_string** in the result is "2020-02-28T17:04:00.000Z" which is outside the range filter!

I tried looking at the docs but no avail. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that has to do with the way a `Range` or a `bucket` is calculated. My understanding is that `28m` of range would have to be maintained throughout i.e. the bucket size must be consistent.

Notice that `28m` of range difference is maintained perfectly and in a way first and the last bucket seem to be stretched just to accommodate this `28m` range.

Notice that logically, your result documents are all in the right buckets and that documents which are outside the filter range *would not be in the aggregation query* irrespective of the `key_as_string` appears within their limits.

Basically ES doesn't guarantee that the `range values i.e. key_as_string` or `start and end values of buckets` created may fall **accurately** within the scope of the filter you've provided but it does guarantee that *only the documents* filtered as per that range filtered query would be considered for evaluation.

You can say that bucket values are nearest possible values or approximations.

If you want to be sure of the filtered documents, just remove the filter from aggregation and use that in the query as below and remove `size: 0`

Notice I've made use of [**offset**](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-datehistogram-aggregation.html#search-aggregations-bucket-datehistogram-offset) which would change the start value of the specified bucket. Perhaps that is something you are looking for.

Also one more thing, I've made use of `min_doc_count` just so you can filter out empty buckets.

```
POST <your_index_name>/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "range": {
            "@timestamp": {
              "gte": "2020-02-28T17:20:10Z",
              "lte": "2020-03-01T18:00:01Z"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "severity_over_time": {
      "date_histogram": {
        "field": "@timestamp",
        "interval": "28m",
        "offset": "+11h",
        "min_doc_count": 1
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation Kamal! That helps!

Comment: @PrakashP If you think your query has been resolved by the above answer, please feel free to upvote and accept the answer by clicking right arrow as mentioned in this link https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/412539

Comment: I got a solution from your explanation. 

But the offset recommendation is confusing for me for the intervals other than day! . e.g. For a day interval an offset of  "+5h" indicates the bucketing will start at 5 am. 

But I cannot understand the "28m" interval with offset of "11h". The bucket interval is just 28 mins but how the offset of "11h" will work here?

Comment: offset +5 doesn't mean it starts at 5am. It means first key would start +5 hrs from the default key time that gets produced. This link would help you. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-datehistogram-aggregation.html#search-aggregations-bucket-datehistogram-offset